# Is it possible to get audio file currently playing position using Aplay?

Tags: alsa

Is it possible to somehow make Aplay tell us what is current audio time position while playing?

Comment: Not in `aplay`, but there are [other command-line players](https://opensource.com/life/16/8/3-command-line-music-players-linux) which give this information.

Answer (score 2):

The aplay utility is too "low-level" and does not provide this kind of output. It can only provide static statistics about the system and the sound file in question.

In theory, `aplay` (or the interfaces it interacts with) must contain some form of playback position, but there is no standard interface to access this. Please consider tools such as [these](https://opensource.com/life/16/8/3-command-line-music-players-linux).